# How to move original email when replied to?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've New Ticket folder, once replied from the New Ticket folder mails have to be moved to Completed folder.

Getting error message

> This method can't be used in an inline response mail item.

at `olMail.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder`.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("In Progress")
    
    Dim olLookUpFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set olLookUpFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("Tickets")
    
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    For Each olMail In olLookUpFolder.Items 'loop through Tickets folder to find original mail
    
        If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, strTicket) > 0 Then 'look for unique ticket Id
    
            olMail.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
    
            Exit For
    
        End If
    
    Next 
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What are the error code and message?

Comment: Thanks and appriciate your quick response.

Comment: Where are you defining `strTicket` and what is its value when the error occurs?

Comment: I'm getting error in this line "olMail.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder".    
                                                                                                                                      Error Message                                                                                                                        
Run-time error'-2147467259 (80004005)

This menthod can't be used with an inline response mail item.

Comment: Done you need any more information

Comment: Even if i define strTicket , error message popsup

Comment: Should be `Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`, and again what is `strTicket`? a subject line?

Comment: Thank you, strTicket- to read the subject line and see if the particular subject line as a response, if so then that mail has to be moved to In progress folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment "strTicket- to read the subject line and see if the particular subject line as a response".
You need `strTicket = "text based on Item.Subject"` for

```
If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, strTicket) > 0
```

For example:
Item.Subject "Re: Ticket #123456"
strTicket would be 123456.

```
If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, strTicket) > 0 Then 'look for unique ticket Id in olLookUpFolder.Items
```

There is no need to extract the unique ticket Id. `olMail.Subject` is unique and will be in `Item.Subject`.
If Item.Subject is "Re: Ticket #123456"
then olMail.Subject is "Ticket #123456"

Reverse the order of the search terms in InStr.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim olNameSpace As NameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim olDestFolder As folder
    Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("In Progress")
    
    Dim olLookUpFolder As folder
    Set olLookUpFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("Tickets")

    ' olMail is a Class. Avoid as a variable name
    'Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olObj As Object ' Outlook items are not necessarily mailitems
    
    For Each olObj In olLookUpFolder.Items 'loop through Tickets folder to find original mail
    
        If olObj.Class = olMail Then
            
            If InStr(1, Item.Subject, olObj.Subject) > 0 Then 'look for olObj.Subject in Item.Subject
                olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                Exit For
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

---

If the preview pane is on then

> Error: "This method can't be used with an inline response mail item."

This code restarted Outlook and disabled VBA the first time. Subsequently it only restarted Outlook. If you get similar results you may decide to turn off the preview pane yourself so the preview pane check is not invoked.

```vb
If InStr(1, Item.Subject, olObj.Subject) > 0 Then 'look for olObj.Subject in Item.Subject
                                                    
    If ActiveExplorer.IsPaneVisible(olPreview) = True Then
                    
        ' Hide Preview Pane
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.ispanevisible
        ActiveExplorer.ShowPane olPreview, False
                    
        olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                    
        ' Show Preview Pane
        ActiveExplorer.ShowPane olPreview, True
                    
    Else
                
        olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                    
    End If
  
    Exit For
                
End If
```

More information about the [error related to inline response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401378/outlook-2013-using-vba-to-send-drafts).