"This method can't be used with an inline response mail item" prevents email from being sent
I created a mailmerge tool with Outlook 365 VBA. It creates emails, gives them a category and saves them in a draft folder. I set up a sub to send the emails that have that category.
When the mail merge generates the emails, none of them have an Action of

This method can't be used with an inline response mail item.

When I run the sub to loop through the draft folder all the emails it finds now have an Action of the above message. This prevents the emails from being sent.
Why does this occur, how do I clear the Action?
Code for the send sub
Sub SendEmailBatch()
    Dim Out_OutlookApp As outlook.Application
    Dim Out_MailItem As outlook.MailItem
    Dim Obj_SendingAccount As Object
    Dim Out_DeliveryFolder As outlook.Folder
    Dim Wrk_WsTable As Worksheet
    Dim Str_AccountName As String
    Dim Str_CategoryName As String
    
    ' Create a new instance of Outlook Application
    Set Out_OutlookApp = New outlook.Application
    
    ' Set reference to the worksheet
    Set Wrk_WsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")
    
    ' Get account name from the worksheet
    Str_AccountName = Wrk_WsTable.Range("G11").Value
    
    ' Get category name from the worksheet
    Str_CategoryName = Wrk_WsTable.Range("G36").Value
    
    ' Find the sending account
    For Each Obj_SendingAccount In Out_OutlookApp.Session.Accounts
        If Obj_SendingAccount.DisplayName = Str_AccountName Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Obj_SendingAccount
    
    ' If the sending account is not found among regular accounts, search among shared mailboxes
    If Obj_SendingAccount Is Nothing Then
        For Each Obj_SendingAccount In Out_OutlookApp.Session.Stores
            If Obj_SendingAccount.DisplayName = Str_AccountName Then
                Set Out_DeliveryFolder = Obj_SendingAccount.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Obj_SendingAccount
    End If
    
    ' Check if the sending account is found
    If Obj_SendingAccount Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sending account not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the items in the drafts folder
    For Each Out_MailItem In Out_DeliveryFolder.Items
        ' Check if the email has the specified category
        If Out_MailItem.Categories = Str_CategoryName Then
            ' Clear conversation index to avoid it being marked as a response
            Out_MailItem.ClearConversationIndex
            ' Set DeferredDeliveryTime to a future time to prevent inline response status
            Out_MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00") ' Delay for 1 minute
            ' Send the email
            
            Out_MailItem.Send
        End If
    Next Out_MailItem
    
    MsgBox "Emails sent.", vbInformation
End Sub

ChatGPT suggested ClearConversationIndex and a deferred delivery time.

This question is similar to: Outlook 2013 using VBA to Send Drafts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639187/how-to-move-original-email-when-replied-to ActiveExplorer.ShowPane olPreview, False Hide Preview Pane

If a message is displayed in the inline response editor, Outlook won't let you invoke MailItem.Send on it; no matter whether you access it from the Drafts folder (where it is stored until sent) or from Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse.
The only workaround is to invoke the Send button using the Accessibility API to find the Send button and simulate a click on it. If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, you can use SafeExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseSend method.
In VBA:
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
sExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseSend


Thank you for the response.
How do the emails get this status anyway and is there a way to avoid it? Is it as simple as them appearing in the preview pane?
As you can tell, i'm new to this, so any help would be much appreciated!

Yes, if an email is displayed in the reading pane, it cannot be sent by calling 'MailItem.Send'.  That's all it takes.

Craziness. I'll try your workaround tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Turns out Redemption is not an option. Is that seriously the only option? Can you not clear or remove the inline response?

You can - as I mentioned, you can use the Accessibility API to simulate a click on the Send button. That is what Redemption does in this particular case.
