# .SentOnBehalfOfName function using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, outlook-2010

I am trying to create an auto-mailer for Outlook with Excel VBA.

I created mailers in the past and the `.SentOnBehalfOfName` function worked.
On those mailers and the new mailer, it no longer works.

I have access to the email address.
I can send emails from that email address, and have in the past.
I can create the email using the mailer and it appears as it should, so the mailer functions are working.

The emails do not display the required email address, but instead my personal work email address.
Now I manually change the email From field.

```vb
Sub Make_Email(Wood As Variant, metal As Variant, SendID As Variant)
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NewSubject As Variant
    Dim InvoiceCount As Integer
    Dim PartnerName As Variant
    Dim Folder As Variant
    Dim EmailLR As Variant
    Dim EmailArray As Variant
    Dim mainWB As Workbook
    Dim CCID
    Dim Subject
    Dim Body
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    Dim Link As Variant
    Dim EmailBody As Variant

    EmailBody = "text of email is here"

    Subject = "Subject text is here"
    With olMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email.this.should.be.from@mycompany.com" 'this is the part that is not working
        .To = SendID
        .Subject = Subject
        .HTMLBody = EmailBody
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I've researched but nothing seems to indicate the `.SentOnBehalfOfName` function has changed or has been removed from use.

I checked the references with my new mailer versus my old mailer and they are all turned on.

- Office 16.0 object library
- Outlook 16.0 object library
- outlook sharepoint social provider
- outlook social provider extensibility
- outlook view control

I've even turned on

- winhttp services version 5.1
- microsoft xml v3.0

I tried a Mr. Excel forum solution to move `.SentOnBehalfOfName` below the `.To` option.
[Using VBA to send Outlook Email / Sent on Behalf Of Name](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vba-to-send-outlook-email-sent-on-behalf-of-name.924670/)

I tried a StackOverflow solution to place the `.SentOnBehalfOfName` as the first statement and then the `.Display`.
[SentOnBehalfOf not working in Excel 2010 VBA Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432256/sentonbehalfof-not-working-in-excel-2010-vba-code)

Comment: I do not have the same environment now but see if an item copied in `ItemSend` will accept `SentOnBehalfOfName`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65042745/1571407